# How to stop matplotlib from incorrectly adding lines at vertical asymptotes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy

For functions that contain vertical asymptotes, y^2 = x^3/(2(3) - x) for example, matplotlib will add in [vertical lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEiT9.png)  at the asymptotes which majorly  throws off the [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7Ebo.png) graph. I am using plot_implicit() from sympy. I have tried setting the adaptive attribute to True which removes the lines but also removes the styling, and for some reason makes the plot line thickness vary and look really [warped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnEPi.png). I would like to keep adaptive=False. For reasons specific to my application I need to use plot_implicit() and can't use contour() or plot() or something else.

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import *
import spb


qVal = "y**2 = x**3/(2*(3) - x)"
x, y = symbols('x y')



cmap = ListedColormap(["teal"], "#ffffff00")

lhs,rhs = qVal.split('=')
lhs = eval(lhs)
rhs = eval(rhs)


plot = spb.plot_implicit(Eq(lhs, rhs),  (x, -10, 10), (
y,-5, 5), adaptive=False,show=True, rendering_kw= {"cmap": cmap}, aspect='equal')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plot_implici` with `adaptive=False` uses a simple meshgrid approach to evaluate a function, and it uses a matplotlib's contour feature to plot the zero-level contour. With "simple" I mean that it doesn't apply any post-processing. You can look at a 3D plot of your function, which also uses the meshgrid approach, to understand what's happening:

```py
expr = lhs - rhs
spb.plot3d(expr, (x, -10, 10), (y,-5, 5), backend=spb.PB, wireframe=True)
```

[image]

Because there is no post-processing on the evaluated data, the plot connects both sides of an asymptote. When you take the zero-level contour, you'll have that vertical line. Sadly, an asymptote detection is currently not implemented for a meshgrid approach.

You can install the [newer release of the module](https://github.com/Davide-sd/sympy-plot-backends) to use `plot_implicit` with `adaptive=True` and custom styling:

```py
plot = spb.plot_implicit(Eq(lhs, rhs),  (x, -10, 10), (y,-5, 5), aspect='equal',
                         adaptive=True, rendering_kw={"color": "r"})
```

[image]

As you noticed, the adaptive algorithm tends to create uneven lines or regions. There is nothing I can do to fix it.

A better approach would be to apply some post-processing to your symbolic equation. For example:

```py
expr = lhs - rhs
sols = solve(expr, y)
spb.plot(*sols, (x, -10, 10), {"color": "b"},
         legend=False, aspect="equal", ylim=(-5, 5))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your timely help. your answer involving spb.plot is working great. I was just wondering if there is a way to prevent the tiny breaks in the lines for some functions where the slope is undefined?

Comment: do you have any examples?

Comment: (y^(2))*(1^(2)-x^(2))=(x^(2)+2*1y-3)^2 , the bicorn function, will plot as a bicorn with line breaks at the bottom two corners

Comment: I've tried both adaptive=True and adaptive=False, I'm not getting line breaks...